# Woocommerce BACS payment gateway account details modify

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering is it possible to change `woocommerce/includes/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php` like a template file in `mytheme/includes/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php`? For this moment I changed code in the plugin core, but after update it will change again.

Or maybe someone knows how to do it in `function.php` file with hook or something like that?

I need to change this function:

```
/**
 * Get bank details and place into a list format.
 *
 * @param int $order_id
 */
private function bank_details( $order_id = '' ) {

    if ( empty( $this->account_details ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get order and store in $order
    $order      = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Get the order country and country $locale
    $country    = $order->billing_country;
    $locale     = $this->get_country_locale();

    // Get sortcode label in the $locale array and use appropriate one
    $sortcode = isset( $locale[ $country ]['sortcode']['label'] ) ? $locale[ $country ]['sortcode']['label'] : __( 'Sort Code', 'woocommerce' );

    $bacs_accounts = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts', $this->account_details );

    if ( ! empty( $bacs_accounts ) ) {
        echo '<h2 class="wc-bacs-bank-details-heading">' . __( 'Our Bank Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h2>' . PHP_EOL;

        foreach ( $bacs_accounts as $bacs_account ) {

            $bacs_account = (object) $bacs_account;

            if ( $bacs_account->account_name || $bacs_account->bank_name ) {
                echo '<h3>' . wp_unslash( implode( ' - ', array_filter( array( $bacs_account->account_name, $bacs_account->bank_name ) ) ) ) . '</h3>' . PHP_EOL;
            }

            echo '<ul class="wc-bacs-bank-details order_details bacs_details">' . PHP_EOL;

            // BACS account fields shown on the thanks page and in emails
            $account_fields = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bacs_account_fields', array(
                'account_number'=> array(
                    'label' => __( 'Account Number', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'value' => $bacs_account->account_number
                ),
                'sort_code'     => array(
                    'label' => $sortcode,
                    'value' => $bacs_account->sort_code
                ),
                'iban'          => array(
                    'label' => __( 'IBAN', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'value' => $bacs_account->iban
                ),
                'bic'           => array(
                    'label' => __( 'BIC', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'value' => $bacs_account->bic
                )
            ), $order_id );

            foreach ( $account_fields as $field_key => $field ) {
                if ( ! empty( $field['value'] ) ) {
                    echo '<li class="' . esc_attr( $field_key ) . '">' . esc_attr( $field['label'] ) . ': <strong>' . wptexturize( $field['value'] ) . '</strong></li>' . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }

            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }

}
```

I really need help with this, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why you don't create a custom payment method, unsetting first Bacs payment method… Try to search in google something like these searches: "how to unset BACS" or "woocommerce unset payment method" and "woocommerce custom payment method". Then you can pick up some code from class-wc-gateway-bacs.php… Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, you gave for me the right way. I created plugin with similar function but different variables and it's working now ;) @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Done. I don't know how to explain it correctly, but I did my best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

I've just created extra file `filename.php` , inserted hook + default `woocommerce/includes/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php` code, changed           `$this->id = 'bacs';` to `$this->id = 'YOUR ID NAME';` and changed all variables with "`bacs`" to "`YOUR ID NAME`". This file goes to plugins folder and activate it in wordpress :)

[Full code example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7uv23yu/)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Payment Gateway
Description: Custom payment gateway 
Author: Baivaras
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

/**
 * Custom Payment Gateway.
 *
 * Provides a Custom Payment Gateway, mainly for testing purposes.
 */
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init_custom_gateway_class');
function init_custom_gateway_class(){

    class WC_Gateway_Custom extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        public $domain;

        /* class-wc-gateway-bacs.php from public function __construct CODE GOES HERE */
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_custom_gateway_class' );
function add_custom_gateway_class( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Custom';
    return $methods;
}
```

Sorry for my english if something was wrong :)

Comment: is necessary to changed ALL variables with 'bacs' to 'YOUR ID NAME'?

Comment: OK, its necessary.